# Match inputs with Array

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an multidimensional array and I've chose to random them, how do I match the user inputs to the random outputs of the multidimensional array?

```
var sentences:Array = new Array();
sentences[0] = "helloworld";
sentences[1] = "applehealthy";
sentences[2] = "lovemoney";
var randomSentences = Math.floor(Math.random()*(3));
```

Comment: Your array is not multidimentional. Your question is not clear. What are you actually trying to do? Please add sample input-output.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a multidimensional Array. But to match up your random number to your array entries you simply need to do this:

```
var randomSentence = sentences[Math.floor(Math.random()*2.99)]
//I've put 2.99 because I'm sure that Math.random() can return 1, and in your case this would cause an error
```

Comment: `Math.random()` does not return 1.